# Spark Structured Streaming Databricks Event Hub Schema Defining issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am having an issue with defining the structure for the json document.
[image]

Now i am trying to do the same schema on streamread.

```
val jsonSchema = StructType([ StructField("associatedEntities", struct<driver:StringType,truck:StringType>, True), 
                          StructField("heading", StringType, True), 
                          StructField("location", struct<accuracyType:StringType,captureDateTime:StringType,cityStateCode:StringType,description:StringType,latitude:DoubleType,longitude:DoubleType,quality:StringType,transmitDateTime:StringType>, True), 
                          StructField("measurements", array<struct<type:StringType,uom:StringType,value:StringType>>, True), 
                          StructField("source", struct<entityType:StringType,key:StringType,vendor:StringType>, True), 
                          StructField("speed", DoubleType, True)])

val df = spark
 .readStream
 .format("eventhubs")
 //.schema(jsonSchema) 
 .options(ehConf.toMap)
 .load()
```

When I run this cell in the notebook ":15: error: illegal start of simple expression
val jsonSchema = StructType([ StructField("associatedEntities", struct, True),"

Edit: The goal is to get the data into a dataframe. I can get the json string from the body of the event hub message but i am not sure what to do from there if i cant get the schema to work.

Comment: Check this SO Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568435/how-to-create-schema-structtype-with-one-or-more-structtypes

Comment: how would i handle array<struct<type:StringType,uom:StringType,value:StringType>> in that .add style ?

Comment: It doesnt seem that schema is needed for the event hub, i am trying to take the binary body col that has the json object and then structure it

Answer (score 1):

You get the error message because of your schema definition. The schema definition should look something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val jsonSchema = StructType(
                        Seq(StructField("associatedEntities", 
                                        StructType(Seq(
                                          StructField("driver", StringType), 
                                          StructField ("truck", StringType)
                                        ))),
                            StructField("heading", StringType),
                            StructField("measurements", ArrayType(StructType(Seq(StructField ("type", StringType), StructField ("uom", StringType), StructField("value", StringType)))))
                           )
                         )
```

You can doublecheck the schema with:

```
jsonSchema.printTreeString
```

Giving you the schema back:

```
root
 |-- associatedEntities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- driver: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- truck: string (nullable = true)
 |-- heading: string (nullable = true)
 |-- measurements: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uom: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

As mentioned in the comments you get binary data. So first you get the raw dataframe:

```
val rawData = spark.readStream
  .format("eventhubs")
  .option(...)
  .load()
```

You have to:

- convert the data to a string
- parse the nested json
- and flatten it

Define the dataframe with the parsed data:

```
val parsedData = rawData
   .selectExpr("cast (Body as string) as json")
   .select(from_json($"json", jsonSchema).as("data"))
   .select("data.*")
```

Comment: i am working through your answer, i am curious what does the seq function do ?